# How can I remove the text before and after a particular character?

Tags: regex, perl

I have been trying to remove the text before and after a particular character in each line of a text. It would be very hard to do manually since it contain 5000 lines and I need to remove text before that keyword in each line. Any software that could do it, would be great or any Perl scripts that could run on Windows. I run Perl scripts in ActivePerl, so scripts that could do this and run on ActivePerl would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to give an example of an input line and the output line you want from it?  Your question is a little ambiguous, and the answers you've gotten so far reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use this:

```
$text =~ s/ .*? (keyword) .* /$1/gx;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need software, you can make this part of your existing script. Multiline **regex** replace along the lines of /a(b)c/ then you can backref b in the replacer with $1. Without knowing more about the text you're working with it's hard to guess what the actual pattern would be.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that you have the following:

> text1 text2 keyword text3 text4 text5 keyword text6 text7

and what you want is

```
s/.*?keyword(.*?)keyword.*/keyword$1keyword/;
```

otherwise you can just replace the whole line with keyword

An example of the data may help us be clearer

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, that if $text contains your whole text, you can do :

```
$text =~ s/^.*(keyword1|keyword2).*$/$1/m;
```

The `m` modifier makes `^` and `$` see a beginning and an ending of line, and not the beginning and ending of the string.

Comment: I think this one won't work, because the `.*$` won't match newlines.

Comment: Of course it won't match the newlines, that's the point of '/m', wasn't that what was asked for ?

Comment: . will match anything but a newline. $ will match after a newline or at the end of a string. If there is a newline between them (as will usually be the case), it won't match.

Comment: If you want to match newlines, use the appropriate modifier. No biggie.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove all text to the left of `keyword1` and all text to the right of `keyword2`:

```
while (<>) {
  s/.*(keyword1)/$1/;
  s/(keyword2).*/$1/;
  print;
}
```

Put this into a perl script and run it like this:

```
fix.pl original.txt > new.txt
```

Or if you just want to do this inplace, perhaps on several files at once:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/.*(keyword1)/$1/; s/(keyword2).*/$1/;' original.txt original2.txt
```

This will do inplace editing, renaming the original to have a .bak extension, use an implicit while-loop with print and execute the search and replace pattern before each print.

To be safe, verify it without the -i option first, or at the very least on only one file...